# Route all traffic through a WireGuard Hub and Spoke VPS (Nftables)

Tags: firewall, routing, vps, wireguard, nftables

As mentioned in the title, I am using a WireGuard Hub and Spoke configuration to connect my network at home to RoadWarrior peers. Unfortunately I have no public IPv4 and v6 address at home and on the road, so I need the hub. So far the routing of private IP addresses works, but I want to use the VPS (HUB and Host B) also as an exit point for normal traffic, because I am sometimes on the road with my mobile in insecure networks. So on my Host A (smartphone) I have set the Allowed-IPs to 0.0.0.0/0, but unfortunately this does not go through. I suspect that routing rules are missing on the VPS (HUB and Host B). Here you have how I thought about the whole thing.

```
RoadWarrior (Host A)   <--->   VPS HUB (Host B)   <---->  Home-net (Host C)
                                    |
                                    |
                                 Internet
```

So here is my WireGuard configuration on the VPS:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.210.1.1/16
ListenPort = 51828
PrivateKey = 

PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
PreUp = nft -f /etc/nftables.wg

PostDown = nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0

# Home-net (Host C)

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.211.1.1/24, 10.1.0.0/16, 10.2.0.0/16


#Road-Warrior Peers (Host A)

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.212.1.1/32
```

My nftables config when WireGuard is running:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

define pub_iface = eth0
define wg_iface = wg0
define wg_port = 51828

table inet basic-filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
                ct state { established, related } accept
                iif lo accept
                ip protocol icmp accept
                ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
                ct state new tcp dport 51829 log prefix "Neue SSH-Verbindung" accept
                iif $pub_iface udp dport $wg_port accept
                iifname $wg_iface accept
                reject
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
                iifname $wg_iface oifname $wg_iface accept
                reject with icmpx type host-unreachable
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}
```

And my WireGuard configuration when WireGuard is down:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table inet basic-filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
                ct state { established, related } accept
                iif lo accept
                ip protocol icmp accept
                ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
                ct state new tcp dport 51829 log prefix "Neue SSH-Verbindung " accept
                reject
        }
}
```

Maybe you can also check out my nftables configuration, because it' relatively new to me :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes (`ip route` ...) weren't provided but I'll assume Host's B routes are already correctly configured by the system and by `wg-quick`.

Since the WG IP addresses are not public they have to be NATed when reaching Internet with a chain hooking in *postrouting*. Add this block, still within the `table inet basic-filter` block:

```
        chain natpostrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                iifname $wg_iface oifname $pub_iface masquerade
        }
```

If the VPS' kernel is too old (older than [kernel 5.5](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=28f8bfd1ac948403ebd5c8070ae1e25421560059)) the input interface name expression has to be replaced with a source address expression instead, which depends on the precise setup. For example, instead of above:

```
        chain natpostrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 oifname $pub_iface masquerade
        }
```

Now, an *nftables* forward rule to allow (above) traffic with Internet is missing. Insert the following two rules in the forward chain before the `reject` statement rule. The second is to allow forwarding from WG to Internet, the first is to allow traffic back in a stateful generic way, just like what's done in the *input* chain.

```
                ct state { established,related } accept
                iifname $wg_iface oifname $pub_iface accept
```

---

There are a few other minor details.

- there shouldn't be the need to install and remove a different *nftables* ruleset when the tunnel is up or down

  but it's at your own convenience.
- rejecting packets that might have been classified as *invalid* can cause TCP connections to abort unexpectedly when receiving delayed packets

  So drop them before rejecting them. Insert this rule anywhere before the final `reject` statement rule, once in the `input` chain and once in the `forward` chain:

  ```
                  ct state invalid drop
  ```

  A [possible future patch](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter-devel&m=165833943106177&w=2) might make this not needed anymore.
- IPv6's *nexthdr* is not directly equivalent to IPv4's *protocol*

  because there can be [extension headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Extension_headers) between the fixed header and the upper-layer protocol header.

  A lot of documentation on Internet has this wrong.

  So this should almost never be used (because it might not match in cases where the intent was to match):

  > ```
  > ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
  > ```

  and be replaced with meta information already known by the system because it correctly parsed the *whole* packet:

  ```
  meta nfproto ipv6 meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
  ```

  or simply:

  ```
  meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I almost figured it out. I have never received such a quick and comprehensive answer in a forum. Thanks also for the help with nft, you are a hero!